# How to set time over x-axis using flot graph?

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using [Flot chart](http://www.flotcharts.org/)  to create line graph . my [code](http://pastebin.com/qzeEZwyK) to display graph over page.But I am trying to show graph only with given times only.But its also showing  other times in between.

How can just show given timings over x-axis.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If you mean the ticks on the x axis, you can set these in the options (see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes)).

Comment: I mean over x axis it must display times which we specify like 10:38 14:45 etc. Flot chart starts with 00:00 to 23:59 over x axis. So my concern was it must ONLY display that dates which I provided to this chart

Comment: That is exactly what the `ticks` option in the link above does.